# Application for simple time-line drawing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, timeline

I've just started working on my thesis and to evaluate my performance, I have come up with a tentative time-line and some deadlines. However, I want to somehow visualize this. I am deeply in need of an app which does this for me, I mean I can actually draw these time-lines, and deadlines. it doesn't have to be really complicated. as long as I can visualize my own progress is fine.Does anyone know of such an application for Linux(Ubuntu)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/calizo/

It is a cross-platform app.